# Using integer argument in python for a for loop

Tags: python

Newbie to python here, I am trying to use an integer as an argument for a for loop. The code I use

```
from sys import argv

script, numberofposts = argv
postsint = int(numberofposts)

for x in range(0,"%d" % postsint):
    print 'on time'

print "number %d" % postsint
```

**Gives me this error** -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "forarg.py", line 6, in <module>
    for x in range(0,"%d" % postsint):
TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got str.
```

What am I doing wrong here? I assumed that it was a syntax issue but the error seems to indicate that the for loop is expecting an integer which I attempted to force as you can see.

Comment: As the error informs you, it's not an integer. You'd be surprised how far you can get if you take the error message seriously.

Comment: I was confused by the documentation here - http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html where it said d for conversion to signed integer decimal. I understand that a bit better now based on the answers below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for x in range(postsint): # start at beginning as mgilson suggested`

should work fine.  You already casted it an integer, You shouldn't be creating a string from it

Answer (score 3):

it's because `"%d"` is used for string formatting and it returns string only:

```
In [18]: type( "%d" % 3)
Out[18]: <type 'str'>
```

use just ,`range(0,4)` or `xrange(0,4)` if you're on python 2.x:

```
In [19]: range(0,4)  #0 is the default value of the first argument, so range(0,4)==range(4)
Out[19]: [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a formatted string as the second param to range.

In the case that you are using you are saying start at 1 and go up to a string with the number `postint` in it.

This is wrong. You want to do `range( 1, postint )`